# How to specify field which is array of objects, objects of array has one of attribute as unique but optional in Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my schema for employee personal information

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PersonalInformationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
emails: [{
        email: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            unique: true
        },
        isPrimary: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('PersonalInformation', PersonalInformationSchema);
```

In my case I have array `emails` which is optional for employee but should be unique. When I insert a record without emails, document saves successfully (with empty array `emails: []`) but in next try it says

```
"err": {
        "driver": true,
        "name": "MongoError",
        "index": 0,
        "code": 11000,
        "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: EmployeePersonalInformation.personalinformations index: emails.email_1 dup key: { : null }"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`sparse: true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#sparse-indexes) to your schema, try:

```
const PersonalInformationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
    emails: [{
            email: {
                type: String,
                trim: true,
                unique: true, 
                sparse: true
            },
            isPrimary: {
                type: Boolean
            }
        }]
    }, {
        timestamps: true
});
```

> The sparse property of an index ensures that the index only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field. The index skips documents that do not have the indexed field.

So when empty documents will be skipped you won't get an error from `unique` constraint.

Comment: I have have tried `sparse: true` but still facing same issue. Also I did flush the collection and tried.

Comment: @THEINN-VISIBLE I tried your schema, reproduced the issue, then added sparse and dropped old collection. Now when I run `db.personalinformations.getIndexes()` I see that there's an index with `sparse: true` and I can insert multiple docs with empty array. Could you confirm that you followed tnat way ?

Comment: It worked when I dropped the collection. What if I don't want lose my old data ?

Comment: @THEINN-VISIBLE this might be a solution in that case: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.syncIndexes